# Strange result for divergent double integral $\int _0^{\infty }\int _0^{\infty }\frac{1}{x^2 y^2+1}dydx$

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

Mathematica 10.1.0 returns a strange result for the following double integral

```
f = Integrate[ 1/(1 + x^2 y^2), {x, 0, ∞}, {y, 0, ∞}]

(* Out[1407]= \!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(∫\), \(0\), \(∞\)]\(
\*FractionBox[\(π\), \(2\ x\)] \[DifferentialD]x\)\) *)
```

in Latex:

$$\int_0^{\infty } \frac{\pi }{2 x} \, dx$$

There is no warning that the result might be infinite or not existent.
Applying `Simplify[]` or `FullSimplify[]` to $f$ does not help. 
Numerically, however, the divergence is revealed

```
f // N
```

> During evaluation of In[1418]:= NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical
>   integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following:
>   singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory
>   integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small. >>

and further error Messages which I have dropped here.

```
(* Out[1418]= 366.404 *)
```

I suggest to consider this behaviour a bug.

Taking finite integration regions reveals the logarithmic divergnce of the double integral:

```
fi = Integrate[ 1/(1 + x^2 y^2), {x, 0, t}, {y, 0, t}, Assumptions -> t > 0]

(* Out[1411]= 1/2 I (PolyLog[2, -I t^2] - PolyLog[2, I t^2]) *)

Series[fi, {t, ∞, 2}] // Normal

(* Out[1416]= 1/t^2 - π Log[1/t] *)

Limit[fi, t -> ∞]

(* Out[1400]= ∞ *)
```

Comment: I do see an Integral::idiv message (in fact two of them).

Comment: Mathematica 11.0.1 gives "Integral of π/(2 x) does not converge on {0,∞}."

Comment: 10.1 gives error message too. Curious, whatever version does not give an error, what does it do if you directly evaluate `Integral[1/x,{x,0,Infinity]`?

Comment: @george2079 1) Again: my version "10.1.0  for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 24, 2015)" does NOT give errors message. If your 10.1 does, is must be a different version. 2) on your test case it says "Integral of 1/x does not converge on {0,\[Infinity]}." 3) version 5.2 as well as 8 correctly give this error message (besides other messages) on the original double integral. Hence it seems to be just "bad luck" in version 10.1.0.

Answer (score 2):

One may use the definition of the double improper integral (see Multivariable improper integrals in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Improper_integral ). Let us calculate

```
r = Integrate[1/(1 + x^2*y^2), {x, 0, a}, {y, 0, b},Assumptions -> a > 0 && b > 0]
```

> 1/2 I (PolyLog[2, -I a b] - PolyLog[2, I a b]

If the improper integral under consideration exists, the one equals $$\lim\limits_{a\to \infty,\,b\to \infty} r $$ and this limit is finite and is equal to the iterated limit $$\lim_{b\to\infty}(\lim_{a\to\infty} r).$$ But

```
Limit[ r, a -> Infinity, Assumptions -> b > 0]
```

> Infinity

Answer (score 2):

In:

```
Integrate[
 1/(1 + x^2 y^2), 
 {x, y} ∈ Rectangle[{0, 0}, {Infinity, Infinity}]]
```

Out:

> Infinity

Comment: Or Integrate[1/(1 + x^2 y^2), {x, y} \[Element] Disk[{0, 0}, Infinity, {0, Pi/2}]]