# Strange results with a double definite integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Doing `Integrate[1/(x y),{x,0,1},{y,0,1}]` returns zero, although the integral is clearly divergent; `NIntegrate` attempts to compute it, then gives up at `2.15434*10^9` with some error messages.

Is there a way to get a correct answer?

There are several complaints here about strange evaluations of integrals, but none of them are quite like this. The closest one, [Strange result for divergent double integral $\int _0^{\infty }\int _0^{\infty }\frac{1}{x^2 y^2+1}dydx$](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/138196/strange-result-for-divergent-double-integral-int-0-infty-int-0-infty) does not have any answers, so I decided to post this as another instance of the same problem.

Comment: What MMA version and operating system are you on? I get the same on 10.0.2.0 on macOS 10.12.4

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer Mine is 11.0.1.0 on WIndows 10

Comment: Version 10.0 gives the error: **"Integral of 1/x does not converge on {0,1}."**

Comment: @mattiav27 I get this with `Integrate[1/x,{x,0,1}]`, and similar error messages with `Integrate[Integrate[1/(x y),{x,0,1}],{y,0,1}]`, but `Integrate[1/(x y),{x,0,1},{y,0,1}]` just returns `0` without any other output

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე I meant that using *your* function, Mathematica gives correctly an error. I meant it works with my version of Mathematica.

Comment: @mattiav27 I see, I just wanted to indicate that also the message you get is not entirely accurate. I wonder whether I should use the [tag:bug] tag...

Comment: I also get 0 with Mathematica 11.1 on Linux. My guess is that this is some kind of regression since 10.0.1 or 10.0.2 that hasn't been fixed.

Comment: I will file a bug report but I should mention that any "simple" fix might turn out to break things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed as of version 11.3.0:

```
Integrate[1/(x y), {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}] // Head
```

> `Integrate::idiv: Integral of 1/(x y) does not converge on {0, 1}.`

```
(* Integrate *)
```

Answer (score 1):

The limit of (Integrate[1/(x y), {x, a, 1}, {y, a, 1} ], a -> 0) is Infinity.

In:

```
Clear[n]
f[a_] := Integrate[1/(x y), {x, a, 1}, {y, a, 1} ]
Limit[f[a], a -> 0]
Table[{10^(-n), f[10^(-n)] // N}, {n, 200, 100, -1}] // 
 ListLinePlot[#, PlotRange -> Full] &
```

Out:
[image]

Comment: As a matter of fact, `Integrate[1/(x y), {x, a, 1}, {y, a, 1} ]` is `Log[a]^2` (under some restrictions on `a`)